Tag a relationship, not a model
In my Laravel app, I have User, List and ListItem models, with a one-to-many relationship between User and List and many-to-many relationships between User and ListItem and between List and ListItem. Each User should be able to tag the ListItems on each List separately, so that ListItem 1 can have different tags on List A and List B. My lists_listitems pivot table has a column "tags" but I don't know how to define a Tag model on a relationship.
I thought about simplifying the problem by creating a Tag model with a many-to-many relationship with ListItems, but as all Users have access to all ListItems in the data base, a ListItem's Tags would then be visible to all Users. And if I would try to make the Tags visible only to one User, I would have the same problem (just for the listitems_user pivot table instead of the lists_listitmes one).
I searched the docs and the web but did not get any useful hits, which might be due to Tags being a very common example for a many-to-many relationship, without the additional complication that my app necessitates. Is it even possible to tag relationships in Laravel?

I don't understand if you want the tags of a list item to be visible to all users or only the tags that the user has added. Can you explain more about having access to tags and what you want to gain from this relationship?

The tags a user added should only be visible to that user. For example, if a musician plays two instruments and organizes the pieces they play in separate lists for each instrument. They might want to tag a piece as 'difficult' for one instrument but not for the other. Another user might assess the difficulty differently, so should be able to use their own tags.

I post an answer, hope to help you. feel free to ask details in comments, I try to answer.

I would make an additional Tag model so the entities would be Tag, User, List, ListItem, with one pivot list_item_user_tags.
I would leave the users table as it is, then the
tags table - id, name, user_id (so the tags are user-specific);
lists table - id, name;
list_items table - id, name; list_item_user_tags table - id, list_id, list_item_id, tag_id, user_id.

Thank you so much for this idea! I'm new to Laravel and didn't know that pivot tables can connect more than two models... list_item_tag might be sufficient, as each list belongs to only one user. I'll try this tomorrow and if it works for my app, I'll accept your answer.

If in the system you are considering, tags are fixed and can be defined as Enums, I suggest you consider a table with columns of user_id, list_id, list_item_id and a tag column whose content is Enum. With this work, every time you access the array of lists or item lists, you can easily have a pivot for the label inside your relationship. The relationship codes for the proposed table will be as follows:
// User model
public function lists(){
    return $this->hasMany(List::class, 'list_id');
}
public function list_items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ListItem::class, 'pivot_table', 'user_id', 'list_item_id')
                ->withPivot(['list_id', 'tag']);
}

//for attach new tag to a list item in a list
$user->list_items()->attach($list_item_id, ['list_id' => $list_id, 'tag' => $tag]);

//for getting list items with tags
$list_items = $user->list_items()->get();
foreach($list_items as $list_item){
    $tag = $list_item->pivot->tag;
    $list_id= $list_item->pivot->list_id;
}

But if the tags could be defined by the user and each user had his own tags, you should also define a model for the Tag. And in the previous proposed table, use the id of this tag instead of the enum. In this case, the relations will be like this:
// User model
public function lists(){
    return $this->hasMany(List::class, 'list_id');
}
public function list_items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ListItem::class, 'pivot_table', 'user_id', 'list_item_id')
                ->withPivot(['list_id', 'tag_id']);
}
public function tags(){
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::class, 'tag_id');
}

//Tag model
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
public function list_items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(ListItem::class, 'pivot_table', 'tag_id', 'list_item_id')
                ->withPivot(['user_id', 'list_id']);
}

//ListItem Model
public function list(){
    return $this->belongsTo(List::class, 'list_id');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'pivot_table', 'list_item_id', 'user_id')
                ->withPivot(['list_id', 'tag_id']);
}

